# Webpack build fails with Gitlab-CI

Tags: linux, webpack, gitlab-ci

When Gitlab-CI is running my pipeline I get an error in the console:

```
$ npm run build

> project-name@1.0.0 build /home/gitlab-runner/builds/1e932413/0/namespace/project-name
> webpack

using environment 'development'
Hash: 4eb3a28e1a75bb9f8fb5
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 70ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  2.75 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./index.js 261 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const root = props => {
|   return(
|       <Provider store={store}>
|           <MyComponent {...props}/>
|       </Provider>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project-name@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project-name@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2018-02-14T11_07_48_546Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I really don't know what causes this error. This is what I have tried so far:

- SSH into the server and run `webpack` gives the same error
- `git status` in the workspace reports no changes
- **copy the workspace somewhere else and running `webpack` is working**
- cloning a fresh copy somewhere else on the server and running `webpack` works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the babel-loader configuration from

```js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['env']
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

to

```js
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['env']
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/370#issuecomment-310378407

Comment: i got the same issue, but i am excluding the build folder already and it does not fix my problem - which is weird anyway, because there is no class property in the build, after running webpack with babel...it just seems like it does not take the babel plugin from .babelrc. works fine locally, does not work in gitlab ci. what runner image are you using? i am using node 8 alpine.

Comment: btw, same with node:8 and node:8-slim :(

Comment: just tried this and it works fine for me with node:alpine