# CI/CD on gitlab fails to compile with babel-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, gitlab-ci

I have a react app with webpack. Dev server works as expected. When I run locally `webpack --mode production` it builds and creates a js bundle as expected. When I push it to gitlab it fails to build it with error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 20:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (20:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| firebase.initializeApp(config);
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
|
```

These are my devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-eslint": "8.2.6",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.6.0",
  "css-loader": "0.28.11",
  "eslint": "4.19.1",
  "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
  "style-loader": "0.21.0",
  "webpack": "^4.28.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
}
```

And this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /build/],
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: path.join(__dirname, 'public/'), to: path.join(__dirname, 'build') }
    ])
  ]
};
```

This was working previously but I updated the libraries was out of date quite much. After update the gitlab ci fails.

This is the build config:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

stages:
    - setup
    - build

setup:
    stage: setup
    script:
        - echo "Setup started"
        - yarn install
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - node_modules/

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - yarn build
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build/
```

**EDIT**
I have transpired index.js so maybe the entry is not good or something, but then I got a bunch of errors inside components that it cannot resolve jsx tags. I suspect `babel-loader` is not working on gitlab-ci.

**EDIT 29.3.2019**
I haven't find a solution for this. As of you can have free private repos on github, migrated the project to github and [setup circleci](https://medium.com/@parohy/circleci-with-firebase-and-react-1cf2eacdbb82). Circleci work for me flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1"
```

To your `devDependencies` and it should work.

The error is coming since you have not provided the `react` and `react-dom` module in the `package.json`.

Let me know if it works for you if not we will look forward for the issue

**UPDATE:**

```
image: node:latest

cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

stages:
    - setup
    - build

setup:
    stage: setup
    script:
        - echo "Setup started"
        - yarn install
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - node_modules/

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - yarn install react
        - yarn install react-dom
        - yarn build
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build/
```

Adding the installation command directly to the script should solve this problem.
Somehow your `webpack` is not finding the installation directory of the `react` and `react-dom` so passing the installation command will explicitly provide the module while building.

Comment: I have those in the dependencies. I just did not copy that to this question as of there is 20+ dependencies

Comment: It should be in your devDependencies. As when the `GitLab` executes your scripts it installs the dependencies from `devDependencies`.

Comment: But I require those two in runtime as well, does it not break the package.json having them in both fields?

Comment: No it wont, I have my own project in GitLab with CI/CD I faced the same issue you are facing. The cause of this problem is that we don't add the devDependencies and it never installs the react then

Comment: Give it a try we will see if anything breaks of the if the `Job` fails

Comment: Can you please add the image of your job from start to end.
It will help me to debug

Comment: Cool thanks, I updated my answer. Just put the installation of React and ReactDOM directly to the Script.

Comment: That sounds a bit contraproductive as of react and reactsom is transfered as node_modules trough artifacts from previous step.

Comment: Yeah.
But inside GitLab runner it is not storing the dependencies properly. If the current solution works, you can remove those two after the successful job. GitLab does not needs the same then.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with Gitlab CI and found out that the exclude was the problem:

```
exclude: [/node_modules/, /build/]
```

Try replacing it with the following:

```
exclude: '/node_modules/',
include: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src')
]
```

It now works locally AND on Gitlab CI for me. Before, it only worked locally.

There is another issue that pointed me to the right direction: [Webpack build fails with Gitlab-CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786401/webpack-build-fails-with-gitlab-ci)